# AWS REST API Gateway Integration Response Mapping - Lambda Error Regex issue

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I would like to return a response code of 400 to the client after throwing an error in my Lambda function. (via REST API - GET)

Here is the response from the Lambda function:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "{\"status\": 400, \"result\": \"Invalid Input\", \"errorDescription\": \"Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD. Refer to our documentation for further instructions.\", \"documentation\": \"link\"}",
  "errorType": "ValueError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 69, in lambda_handler\n    raise ValueError(date_error_json)\n"
  ]
}
```

In the settings of the Integration Response of the API I set up the Lambda Error Regex as `.*"status":400.*`

For the mapping template I have:

```
#set ($errorMessageObj = $util.parseJson($input.path('$.errorMessage')))
{
    "status" : "$errorMessageObj.status"
}
```

When calling the API I mostly receive this result:

```
{"errorMessage": "{\"status\": 400, \"result\": \"Invalid Input\", \"errorDescription\": \"Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD. Refer to our documentation for further instructions.\", \"documentation\": \"link\"}", "errorType": "ValueError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 69, in lambda_handler\n    raise ValueError(date_error_json)\n"]}
```

And the status of the HTTP request tracked in Chromes Developer Tools shows as 200.

My assumption is that the Regex is incorrect since it should at least return a 400 HTTP response, even if my mapping template was incorrect.

However, surprisingly a few times I was able to get the desired result of a 400 HTTP response, as well as the desired format displayed as:

```
{
    "status" : "400"
}
```

The way I got to this result was the following: When I changed the Regex around to `.*400.*` (which did not help) and then back to `.*"status":400.*`. However, as soon as I send another request to the API it was back to the situation before. (No other changes were made, only a second API request)

And this is actually repeatable, every time I switch back and forth between those Regex values I get my desired result. For 1 API request and then it switches back.

I know it sounds weird. Here is a quick screenshare of it: https://www.loom.com/share/365a7c48119944658e157c5e0a5178e8

I would like to know if there is an issue with my code or if this might be a bug on Amazon's end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across the same problem in the future. I have found out the following 2 things:

1. After trying again to set `.*400.*` a little later it worked fine. Of course, this may not be a good idea, because if you return any results, that contain 400 anywhere in their response, they could incorrectly trigger a 400 HTTP response.
2. The workaround I found was to use `.*Invalid Input.*`. Since it is not expected that regular results returned from the API would contain this phrase, this should work reliably.